# File rename through php

Tags: php, xampp

I have the code for file rename;

```
    <?php
$directory= 'J:\xampp\htdocs\rename\abc';
$handler = opendir($directory);
$index = 1;
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      rename($directory."/".$file, $directory."/".$index.".JPG");
        $index++;
    }

}
closedir($handler);
?>
```

Instead of renaming file as 1,2,3,4,....22
it renames the files as
1,10,11,12,13,14,15,.......

Any answer would be welcomed

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Maybe you have a name conflict with an existing file?

Comment: The rename is working properly but they are sorted by name and you see 2, 3, 4 after 19

Comment: Maybe you are just not sorting the directory correctly when you view it

Comment: If you want to sort them properly you should use `natsort`

Comment: Why does it really matter in what order the files are renamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct, as stated in the comment it might be a sorting  problem. To prevent this I usually "pad" my number with leading zero :

- 01.JPG
- 02.JPG
- ...
- 10.JPG

I use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) :

```
$index = str_pad($index, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Your code would look like this :

```
$directory= 'J:\xampp\htdocs\rename\abc';
$handler = opendir($directory);
$index = 1;
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $index = str_pad($index, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        rename($directory . "/" . $file, $directory . "/" . $index . ".JPG");
        $index++;
    }

}
closedir($handler);
```

I you have less than a hundred file you should pad with 1 zero, less than a thousand pad with 2 zeros and so on.

Hope this helps